# Method parameters seem dynamic, not sure how this works

Tags: c#, delegates, dynamic-languages

If I have a delegate and a method

```
public delegate void SomeDelegate(String p);

void aMethod(String p) {
}
```

And then I try to invoke this on a new thread like so

```
SomeDelegate sd = new SomeDelegate(aMethod());
sd.BeginInvoke("heyhey", callBack, null)
```

The BeginInvoke method call now accepts a string as the first parameter, however, if I remove the "String p" from the delegate and the aMethod(), BeginInvoke now only requires two parameters.

How can I build a function like BeginInvoke that dynamically accepts different types of parameters based on code elsewhere?

Sorry If Im being vague here but I've never seen this before and I'm very curious.

Answer (score 4):

I think what you're missing is the fact that the `Invoke`/`BeginInvoke`/`EndInvoke` methods aren't defined on `Delegate` - they're automatically generated for the delegate type by the compiler.

When you originally declare

```
public delegate void SomeDelegate(String p);
```

the compiler generates:

```
public class SomeDelegate : Delegate
{
    public SomeDelegate(Object target, IntPtr method) { ... }

    public virtual IAsyncResult BeginInvoke(string p, 
        AsyncCallback callback, object @object) { ... }

    public virtual void EndInvoke(IAsyncResult result) { ... }

    public virtual void Invoke(string p) { ... }
}
```

(with appropriate method bodies, attributes etc).

When you change the signature of SomeDelegate to remove the parameter, the generated type changes to:

```
public class SomeDelegate : Delegate
{
    public SomeDelegate(Object target, IntPtr method) { ... }

    public virtual IAsyncResult BeginInvoke(
        AsyncCallback callback, object @object) { ... }

    public virtual void EndInvoke(IAsyncResult result) { ... }

    public virtual void Invoke() { ... }
}
```

There's nothing really dynamic going on - you changed the signature of `SomeDelegate`, and that changes the signature of `SomeDelegate.BeginInvoke`. Nothing mysterious.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that is Intellisense doing it's job for delegates.

You could probably define a method with the **params** keyword to have a method accept a variable amount of parameters, but until C# 4.0 is released (it has optional and named parameters), I'm not sure you can do stuff like that yourself.

Of course, I could be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

This is called method overloading. You can find a tutorial [here](http://csharp.net-tutorials.com/classes/method-overloading/).

EDIT:

Then I probably misunderstood your question.

If you a looking how to accept different parameters without overloading you use:

```
public void MyMethod(params object[] args)
{
  foreach (object o in args)
  {
    Type t=o.GetType();
    // do something with o depending on the type
    if (t==typeof(int))
    {
      int i=(int)o; 
      // ...
    }
    else if (t==typeof(string)) // etc.
    {
    }
  }
}
```

You can then call:

```
MyMethod(5, "foo", 7.77);
MyMethod("foo", "bar");
// etc.
```

Comment: I know what overloading is, but this is different.

Answer (score 0):

It's not quite clear what you want to do. If you want to know how to create a new delegate with different parameters you do it as:

```
public delegate void SomeDelegate(String p, string q);
private static void aMethod(string p, string q) 
{
    Console.WriteLine(p + q);
}
```

and to use the delegate:

```
SomeDelegate sd = new SomeDelegate(aMethod);
sd.BeginInvoke("heyhey", "yoyo" callback, null);
```

If on the other hand you want to start a new thread by calling a method without having a previously defined delegate you can use:

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(delegate { aMethod("heyhey", "yoyo"); });
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not something you can do. You are not as powerful as the compiler!